# Выдаёт ошибку AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'

Tags: python

хотел сделать простенькую систему двумерного перемещения, но в генераторе пространства выдаёт AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update' на 36 строке

`

```
 #player
p_pos_x = 0
p_pos_y = 0
#modules
from random import *
#max
max_pos_x = 3
max_pos_y = 3
max_pos_x_ = -3
max_pos_y_ = -3
#playground
pg = {}
#gen
pos = -3
pos_y = -3
num = 0
y_o = {}
y_t = {}
y_th = {}
y_f = {}
y_fi = {}
y_s = {}
y_se = {}
while True:
    num += 1
    dot = {num: pos}
    pos += 1
    if pos == max_pos_x_:
        pos = -3
        num = 0
        pos_y += 1
        if pos_y == max_pos_y:
            break
    if pos_y == -3:
        y_o = y_o.update(dot)
    elif pos_y == -2:
        y_t = y_t.update(dot)
    elif pos_y == -1:
        y_th = y_th.update(dot)
    elif pos_y == 0:
        y_f = y_f.update(dot)
    elif pos_y == 1:
        y_fi = y_fi.update(dot)
    elif pos_y == 2:
        y_s = y_s.update(dot)
    elif pos_y == 3:
        y_se = y_se.update(dot)
#screen
print(y1)
```

`

Comment: пометьте в коде какая строка или приведите полный текст ошибки, а то высчитывать 36 строк не интересно + гадать откуда нумерация

Comment: 1. Откуда у вас берется `y1`? 2. Вместо  `y_o = y_o.update(dot)` используйте `y_o.update(dot)` и ниже по аналогии. 3. Как вы останавливаете бесконечный `while True`?

Answer (score 1):

у вас во всех строчках с `.update()` ОШИБКА

потому что update() ничего не возвращает и уж тем более не возвращает измененный словарь

а раз функция ничего не возвращает, она возвращает `None` и вы просто затираете словарь этим `None`

вместо

```
y_se = y_se.update(dot)
```

надо делать

```
y_se.update(dot)
```

P.S.

подробнее можете почитать

https://pythonz.net/references/named/dict.update/